# Errors raised twice in when inherited model object validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Subclass validations as well as superclass validations implemented. How to discard superclass validations in subclass?
My code:

```
class a < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :price
end

class a2 < a
  validates_presence_of :price
end
```

When I am creating a object for a2, using following command:

```
x = a2.new
x.save
```

the following errors are displayed:

```
x.errors.full_messages
=> ['price can't be blank','price can't be blank']
```

How can I resolve this, so that validations of superclass are ignored.

Comment: Why you validate in the derived and the base class?

Comment: I have to do that, but I also need to get only one validation error.

Answer (score 0):

The two error messages are expected according to your code.

What you did on inherited model is to add one more validation to the validation **chain**, instead of overwrite it.

Comment: How can I overwrite it?

Comment: It seems not so easy and no convention way. check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309757/removing-or-overriding-an-activerecord-validation-added-by-a-superclass-or-mixin My opinion, if the super class is written by you, don't write such validators there.

Comment: Thank you, I managed the validations using :if => 'called a function that checks the class', i.e. x.class == a

Comment: @schipitch, it's okay you solved it though I don't like this. The super class managed something not belonging to him.

Comment: I know, it is a temporary fix, I will anyhow get rid of the subclass soon, that's why, but i will still try to see if there is an easier and better way.

Comment: @schipitch, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/692448. Similar to your method but better because parent class doesn't mention children's names.

Comment: Yeah, this is an easier method, good, I will try this out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using "Add to errors" unless errors.added? which works fine.