# skip validation in parent class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a few classes deriving from A.
A does some validation
In the specific case of class B that inherits from A, I'd like to skip the validation.

I'm using active interaction btw

```
class A < ActiveInteraction::Base
  string :s

  validate :valid
        
  private

  def vaild
    #raise something unless s equals "banana"
  end
end


class B < A 
  #do something here to skip A's validation??          
  def execute
    #super cool logic
  end
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable a validation and callbacks in a rails STI derived model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279478/how-can-i-disable-a-validation-and-callbacks-in-a-rails-sti-derived-model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a subclass, you can override the `valid` method to do *something else*, or even *nothing*:

```
class B < A       
  def execute
    #super cool logic
  end

  private

  def valid
    # Do nothing
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a callback for selectively skipping the validation:

```
class A < ActiveInteraction::Base
  string :s

  validate :valid, unless: :skip_validation
        
  private

  def vaild
    # raise something unless s equals "banana"
  end

  def skip_validation
    false
  end
end


class B < A 
  def execute
    #super cool logic
  end

  private

  def skip_validation
    true # or more fancy logic
  end
end
```